# Ruby on Rails: link inside a gmaps marker description box redirects to a url appended to my website url

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, hyperlink

So I am using the rails 'link_to' method to redirect a user to an external website upon clicking on it (where the link is inside a google maps marker info box). I am using the Gmaps4rails gem. I am building the link inside the marker info window as below, in one of my controllers, where each @locations has a website as one of its attributes:

```
@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@locations) do |location, marker|

  link = view_context.link_to "#{location.website}", location.website, target: "_blank"    
  description = "Website: #{link}"  
  marker.infowindow description

end
```

Everything gets plotted fine, and the links work fine for about half the markers, where if you click on the website link in the description you get redirected to the website in a new tab.

However, there are some website links in which my code acts strange; clicking on the url redirects you to my "website url + the marker's website url", concatenated into one url.Why is this happening?

For example, the url upon clicking on some of the website links in the markers redirects you to a url like this: "mywebsite.com/www.website_in_marker.com". And of course I get a page you are looking for does not exist error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely that some of the links do not have a protocol (http, https, etc.) prepended to it. Anything in the href without a protocol is assumed to be a relative path, which is why some links are appended in relation to your site and others are not.

Going through and ensuring all links include a protocol would be one way to resolve the issue.

Hope it helps!